# File Could not be Attached; Creating and sending a PDF with Activity Intent

Tags: java, android

I've asked a similar question to this before, however, I have done some more research and I am still struggling to figure out what my problem is. Essentially, what I am trying to do is create a form of receipt in a `PDF` format after a customer has completed their purchase. This newly created `PDF` needs to then be sent to a separate emailing client (such as Gmail) through an `Intent`. Compared to my previous question I have now implemented a `FileProvider`, however I keep getting two different errors. The first one is:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content...requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

This causes the file to not be attached to the email at all. And the second error I can sometimes get is, that it will place the actual URI path into the Recipients section of the email, which you can see below (also causing the file to not be attached)

[image]

I have tried quite a few different solutions upon doing my research, such using `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` or `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`, which can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467696/android-file-provider-permission-denial)

I've also seen that some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62332302/permission-denial-coulnt-attach-file-file-requires-the-provider-be-exported) that said to use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the manifest, however, this will then limit my minimum APK level quite a lot.

I even tried what this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650632/fileprovider-not-working-with-camera/33652695#33652695) suggests, whereby you manually go through and give permissions to all the packages, which still didn't solve my problem.

I've also tried using the `grantUriPermission()` method, which still didn't work either.

Below, you will see that I have placed some code:

**Manifext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fabricanddecor">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.example.fabricanddecor"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Method that creates the email and fires Intent (EDIT)**

```
try {
            String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File file = new File(directory);
            if (file.mkdirs()) {
                String filePath = directory + "/sale.pdf";
                File file2 = new File(filePath);
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example.fabricanddecor", file2);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                getContext().grantUriPermission("com.example.fabricanddecor", contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipient);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
                intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email Service"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated, and thank you for your time. If any further code is required, I will be happy to oblige.

Comment: In your manifest, you define the provider with: android:exported="false" have you tried setting it to true? seeing as that's what the error you write requires

Comment: `catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.e("File Error", "error" + ioe.toString());
        }` After such an exception you do as it was not there and you continue with the intent. Instead you should stop then of course. Display a toast so the user knows.

Comment: You are creating a pdf file and then sharing it. Those are two things. If you can create a pdf file then you do not need to post that code. Please post only code that is problematic. I think only sharing is problematic.

Comment: `file.mkdirs();` only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet. And check the return value. If it returns false then stop/return and display a toast.

Comment: `String fileDirectory = directory+"sale.pdf` ? Directory? Better name it: `String filePath = directory+"sale.pdf";`

Comment: But... Why did you add that trailing slash for `directory'? Remove it so you can use `String filePath = directory +"/sale.pdf";`

Comment: @blackapps Sorry about that, I meant to include it just for context sake, I will edit it to be more precise. I also didn't notice the the fact that it wasn't in my try clause, so thank you for picking that up for me. I renamed all the one variable, removed `mkdirs()` and also removed the trailing slash

Comment: You should not remove mkdirs when you are trying to create your file.

Comment: `document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            document.close();` Remove those lines as you now post code for sharing an existing file.

Comment: @blackapps Would the code look something like what I added ?

Comment: @DanBaruch Setting it to `True` crashes the app on startup, I've read that users battle with this problem when running the app on Android Q

Comment: No. As you blindly call mkdirs. Look at my comment about mkdirs how to do it instead. But... If you wanna share a file then... You wil not create a directory there as of course it exists already otherwise your file would not exist either.